# Two identical VPS hosts with different ways of handling file names

Tags: linux, centos, nginx, vps, php-fpm

I have CentOS 6.5 32 bit, 512 RAM, running Nginx, PHP-FPM, Mysql on two hosts. One for local dev, running inside a VirtualBox 4.3.12 and the other running online with digital ocean.

Both of these hosts have software and memory, but I always get errors when uploading my PHP projects from my local to my online VPS.

Here is an example.

```
#bootstrap.php
require '/var/www/public/example.com/ClassLoader.php
```

but the actual file is classloader.php (all small cases)

Now, in my local developer this require does not issue any error, but in my online server I get error, and errors like that everywhere.

My question is, why does this happen in my production server, but not my local? and how do I fix it (enable my production server to ignore case sensitivities)

Comment: Easiest way: make a symlink so classloader.php -> ClassLoader.php. Linux is case-sensitive in all ways and you can't change it.

Comment: But I have many files, do I have to create symlink for all? Plus, my virtualbox is running Linux, but without any of this problem. So, How can I apply the same behaviour to my prod server

Comment: Are you doing anything like sharing a directory from Windows to your virtualbox VM and running your dev code from that?

Comment: Yes. In my Virtualbox, I am sharing the entire `/www` folder. I guess this is the problem, right?

Comment: yes...Windows isn't case sensitive but Linux is...that'd be your problem.